# Darken background around fragments layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout

I've two fragments.

**FragmentBackground** - fragment that takes all size of the screen

**FragmentForeground** - smaller fragment on top of the FragmentBackground

I'm look for a way to dim everything around FragmentForeground layout, meanwhile supporting API 4.0+. Looking for some clean solution here. Open to every suggestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:elivation="8dp"` this might put the fragment up. But it wont support the older versions of android. i would also suggest creating the FragmentBackground and then FragmentBackground . In this way your requirement can be achieved.